# Create a globally accessible node.js module

Tags: node.js, module, global

I would like to create a globally accessible node.js module, like `express` and `mocha`.

So I dived into their source code, and created the following short example:

The *index.js* file, located in the *hello/* directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log("Hello world!")
```

As you can see, it's just a "hello world" to test the concept.

And here is the *package.json* file located in the same *hello/* directory:

```
{
  "name": "Hello",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "./index",
  "bin": {
    "hello": "./bin/hello"
  }
}
```

And then, I tried to install the node app with *npm* with the following:

```
sudo npm install -g hello/
```

But this return an error:

```
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/Hello/bin/hello'
```

I don't know what is wrong, since I respected the module structure like I found it on `express` and `mocha`. Can you provide me a help by:

- pointing what's wrong in my case
- linking to useful tuts and resources about creating executable node modules

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to install the directory.

If you want to install the module locally for you, just copy it to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/`.

However, if you want `npm` to install it (to share), you will have to create a package.

```
npm login
npm publish
npm install -g hello
```

If you are shy, `npm unpublish` will remove it.

Comment: Thanks J for your help, but I would like to test it locally before pushing the module. I addition, it could be heavy to push each update in order to check module updates.